What OS can run the face_recognition library on the Raspberry pi 4?
I am having trouble finding an OS for the raspberry pi 4 that can run the face_recognition library, the ones I have used have not seemed to allow me download it, or the necessary libraries for it (dlib, wheels, cmake).
I have tried on two versions of the raspbian OS, the Raspberry pi OS 64 bit and the Legacy 32 bit.
